# apache log stats by unique subdomain

Tags: bash, apache

I have logs that look like this:

```
IP - - [24/Jul/2015:20:37:05 -0500] "GET /index.php/home/keep_alive?_=1437674521350 HTTP/1.1" 200 10 "https://subdomain.phppointofsale.com/index.php/sales" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
IP - - [24/Jul/2015:20:37:08 -0500] "GET /index.php/home/keep_alive?_=1437621697498 HTTP/1.1" 200 10 "https://demo.phppointofsale.com/index.php/config" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
```

I would like a script that will take input from stdin and product the following:

```
subdomain.phppointofsa.cocm --> 100 HITS
demo.phppointofsale.com --> 200 Hits
```

I know I could probably install analytics software; but for my purposes I need a simple script.

Right now I can do a search via:

```
cat all.log | grep -F 'https://demo.phppointofsale.com' | wc -l > demo.log
```

But I am looking for summary info.

EDIT:

I tried:

```
cmuench-air:logs cmuench$ cat all.log | grep -oP '//\K.*?(?=/)' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,"-->",$1,"Hits"}'
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
cmuench-air:logs cmuench$
```

Edit 2:

I tried the command in the answer below and here is the output:

```
cmuench-air:log_parser cmuench$ awk -F/ '{sub(/.*https:[/][/]/, ""); sub(/[/].*/, ""); c[$0]++;} END{for (domain in c)print domain,"-->",c[domain],"Hits";}' tmp/all.log
awk: extra ] at source line 1
 context is
     >>> {sub(/.*https:[/] <<< 
awk: nonterminated character class .*https:[
 source line number 1
```

EDIT 3:

ALMOST THERE:

I got the subdomain results but I also get lots of IP results mixed in such as:

```
207.161.207.13 - - [13 --> 1 Hits
- - - [25 --> 1 Hits
- - - [26 --> 1 Hits
24.77.198.84, 66.249.84.186 - - [10 --> 1 Hits
192.168.111.143, 203.104.27.52 - - [16 --> 1 Hits
207.161.207.13 - - [14 --> 2 Hits
demopos.phppointofsale.com --> 2 Hits
103.245.159.77 - - [25 --> 1 Hits
```

EDIT 4:

here are some odd logs where no subdomain is present. Can we filter these out somehow?

```
207.161.207.13 - - [26/Jun/2015:18:16:58 -0500] "GET /index.php/login HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
207.161.207.13 - - [26/Jun/2015:18:16:59 -0500] "GET /index.php/home HTTP/1.1" 200 23035 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
```

EDIT 5:

I added a grep filter to the command:

```
awk -F/ '{sub(/.*https:\/\//, ""); sub(/\/.*/, ""); c[$0]++;} END{for (domain in c)print domain,"-->",c[domain],"Hits";}' tmp/all.log | grep -F '.phppointofsale.com' | sort;
```

Is this the best way?

Comment: From the error message `grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ]` it looks like you do not have the `-P` option on your system. You won't be able to use the -P and so also not the `\K`. And BTW, useless use of `cat` : just use `grep -options 'pattern' file | sort ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{sub(/.*https:[/][/]/, ""); sub(/[/].*/, ""); c[$0]++;} END{for (domain in c)print domain,"-->",c[domain],"Hits";}' all.log
subdomain.phppointofsale.com --> 1 Hits
demo.phppointofsale.com --> 1 Hits
```

If your awk does not support character classes, such as `[/]`, then try:

```
awk '{sub(/.*https:\/\//, ""); sub(/\/.*/, ""); c[$0]++;} END{for (domain in c)print domain,"-->",c[domain],"Hits";}' all.log
```

Or, try this one:

```
awk -F/ '{sub(".*https://", ""); sub("/.*", ""); c[$0]++;} END{for (domain in c)print domain,"-->",c[domain],"Hits";}' all.log
```

#### EDIT 4

EDIT 4 adds to more log entries:

```
$ cat all2.log
IP - - [24/Jul/2015:20:37:05 -0500] "GET /index.php/home/keep_alive?_=1437674521350 HTTP/1.1" 200 10 "https://subdomain.phppointofsale.com/index.php/sales" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
IP - - [24/Jul/2015:20:37:08 -0500] "GET /index.php/home/keep_alive?_=1437621697498 HTTP/1.1" 200 10 "https://demo.phppointofsale.com/index.php/config" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
207.161.207.13 - - [26/Jun/2015:18:16:58 -0500] "GET /index.php/login HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
207.161.207.13 - - [26/Jun/2015:18:16:59 -0500] "GET /index.php/home HTTP/1.1" 200 23035 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
```

The latter two lines do not specify a URL.  We can ignore them as follows:

```
$ awk -F/ '/https/{sub(".*https://", ""); sub("/.*", ""); c[$0]++;} END{for (domain in c)print domain,"-->",c[domain],"Hits";}' all2.log
subdomain.phppointofsale.com --> 1 Hits
demo.phppointofsale.com --> 1 Hits
```

Alternatively, if we want to include those lines and list them under `-`, we can use:

```
$ awk -F'"' '{sub("https://", "", $4); sub("/.*", "", $4); c[$4]++;} END{for (domain in c)print domain,"-->",c[domain],"Hits";}' all2.log
subdomain.phppointofsale.com --> 1 Hits
- --> 2 Hits
demo.phppointofsale.com --> 1 Hits
```

Comment: I get error (cmuench-air:log_parser cmuench$ awk -F/ '{sub(/.*https:[/][/]/, ""); sub(/[/].*/, ""); c[$0]++;} END{for (domain in c)print domain,"-->",c[domain],"Hits";}' tmp/all.log
awk: extra ] at source line 1
 context is
  >>> {sub(/.*https:[/] <<< 
awk: nonterminated character class .*https:[
 source line number 1

Comment: @ChrisMuench What OS and what version of awk are you using?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.11 awk version 20070501

Comment: @ChrisMuench OK.  I added a second version.  Let me know if it works better.

Comment: I am trying now. It runs without error but needs to process a 1.8 GB file

Comment: We are almost there. I am seeing some IP addresses mixed in there. I am not sure why. I am looking at logs

Comment: @ChrisMuench That means that there are lines in `all.log` that do _not_ look like the sample input shown in the question.  You need to select some of those problematic lines and display them in another EDIT.

Comment: Your way seems better; trying now.